# How to properly style Java code in Selenium tests

Tags: java

I'm trying to find good information on how should I write (style) my Java code, particularly when it comes to automation, Selenium and its tests.

As an example, I don't know if it's correct or more readable if I do the following:

```
new PageObject
   .clickOnThisButton()
   .doThis()
   .doThat();
```

or just write everything in the same line until it reaches the 80 or 100 character limit `new PageObject.clickOnThisButton().doThis().doThat();`

For me the first approach is more readable, because we're talking about a sequence, a script.
But then, it doesn't make much sense I guess, when it comes to other methods or classes, e.g. `new String("just a string").replace().uppercase();`

Hope what I'm asking makes some sense.

Comment: Your first example illustrates [fluent style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).  It's not  necessarily "better".  It's just matter of "personal preference".

Comment: Interesting, thank you for sharing that.
I was just hoping that there was conventional way to write certain stuff.

Comment: The examples on [Selenium.dev](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/first_script/) write the code in-line (e.g. `WebElement textBox = driver.findElement(By.name("my-text"));`.  Fluent style is a perfectly reasonable alternative, if you and your team like it. The important thing is to *BE CONSISTENT* :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say going with that approach would definitely make your code more readable. But the key is to not overdo it like you you have pointed out. Having a readable test layer can help freshers and not so technical members of your team understand the test automation better.

Method chaining and sugar methods are gaining popularity in Java based automation sphere, maybe because the concepts are popular in JavaScript based automation frameworks they're crossing over.